# How to run windows phone 8 gyroscope in the background?

Tags: background, windows-phone-8, gyroscope

I am trying to create a windows phone 8 application that uses gyroscope.  I would like to run this application in the background.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone applications cannot run continuously in the background.

Additionally there are only a certain APIs that can be used in background agents. The `Gyroscope` is in the `Miscrosoft.Devices.Sensors` namespace and this is [one of the namespaces that cannot be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Even if it was possible, the best you could do would be to have it run for a few seconds every half hour or so but this would be, I imagine, of very little value.

So, in summary: you cannot use the gyroscope in the background.